# Prove that a point $A$ belongs to a unknown function $f$

Tags: functions, continuity

> I have a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for
>   which is true that: $$f(f(x))+f(x)=8,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$$ Also
>   $f(1)=3$. Now I want to prove that the point $A(3,01, 4,99)$ belongs
>   to the graphical representation $(C_f)$ of function $f$. So I need to
>   prove that $$f(3,01)=4,99$$

With Bolzano Theorem at $[3,5]$ I can prove that $f$ has at least one solution $x_0\in(3,5)$ for which $f(x_0)=4,99$, but how can I specify that $x_0=3,01$? Any ideas or tell me if I am completely wrong.

**For Bolzano Theorem**

From the given relationship if I put $x=1$ I get $f(3)=5$ and for $x=3$ I get $f(5)=3$. I applied the theorem at the equation $g(x)=f(x)-4,99$. The function $g$ is continuous at $[3,5]$ as acts between continuous functions and $g(3)=f(3)-4,99=5-4,99=0,01>0$ and $g(5)=f(5)-4,99=3-4,99=-1,99<0$. So $g(3)\cdot g(5)<0$ and therefore from Bolzano Theorem I get that the equation $g(x)=0\iff f(x)-4,99=0\iff f(x)=4,99$ has at least one solution $x_0\in(3,5)$ for which is true that $f(x_0)=4,99$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done. Just iterate once more: $f(f(x_0))+f(x_0)=f(4,99)+4,99=8$ which implies that $f(4,99)=3.01$. Hence, $$f(f(4.99))+f(4.99)=f(3.01)+3.01$$